# QSlider C++ трекинг

Tags: c++, linux, qt5, clion

Как при изменении значения слайдера вызывать определённый метод? Пробовал вот так, но CLion выдаёт ошибку:

```
connect(slider, SIGNAL(valueChanged()), this, SLOT(update()));
```

Ошибка:

```
QObject::connect: No such signal QSlider::valueChanged(1)
```

Comment: valueChanged(int)

Comment: @Fat-Zer запишите ответом, хоть правильным помечу...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
connect(slider, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)), this, SLOT(update()));
```

С точки зрения Qt `valueChanged(int)` и `valueChanged()` — разные сигналы.